# Условие нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android

Есть ли метод, определяющий, нажата ли кнопка?

У меня есть цикл, мне в нем необходимо определить, нажата ли кнопка, и выполнить действие, если нажата.

Вот пример кода

```
for (int i = 0; i < LearnWordHelp.countCategories; i++) {
        View page = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.page_categories_learn_word, linLayout, false);

        TextView tvLearnWortTextTitle = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.tvLearnWortTextTitle);
        tvLearnWortTextTitle.setText(LearnWordHelp.masCategories[i]);

        TextView tvNumberPopularWord = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.tvNumberPopularWord);
        tvNumberPopularWord.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.number_word) + " " + LearnWordHelp.masCountWordAll[i]);

        ImageView imgBackground = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.imgBackground);
        imgBackground.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(LearnWordHelp.masCategoriesCard[i]));

        page.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        linLayout.addView(page);

        CardView cvWordCategories = (CardView) page.findViewById(R.id.cvWordCategories);
        cvWordCategories.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (isPressed){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LearnWord.this, LearnWordHelp.masClass[i]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    isPressed = true;
}
```

Я в цикле создаю карточки, и мне необходимо открыть новый экран при нажатии на кнопку с соответствующем классом.

Но такой код результата не дал, т.к. вначале цикл доходит до конца а потом вызывается метод.

Comment: К кнопке нужно добавить event listener и в определенном методе менять значение переменной, например bool isButtonPress на true, если кнопку нажали, и менять обратно на false, если отбросили

Comment: Сколько времени выполняется цикл?

Comment: Вам в секундах или в итерациях?

Comment: И в секундах и в итерациях

Comment: А есть разница?На данный момент 3 итерации, но берется по длине массива

Comment: Тогда непонятно что вам надо. Вы хотите сделать список, и при клике на элемент списка (или кнопку в элементе), открывалась новая активити с тем элементом по которому кликнули?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно

Comment: Тогда используйте ListView и его метод setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Должно получится что то вроде этого

```
  boolean isButtonPressed = false;
  ...

  button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           isButtonPressed = true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           isButtonPressed = false;
        }
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотри ты можешь когда кнопка была нажата сохранить результат в переменную и потом проверять если она true, тогда выполнять условие.

```
 boolean cl = false;
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
public void onClick (View v) {
    mText.setText("Click1");
    cl = true; // переменная в которой хранится событие нажатия
 }
```

Comment: Я немного подредактировал вопрос. Можете посмотреть еще раз?

Comment: в этом случае вы получите c1 = true только когда кнопка будет нажата и отпущена, но не просто нажата и зажата!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код ужасен, уж простите, но попахивает процедурщиной, вам бы об ООП почитать. Чтобы обрабатывать нажатие, вам необходимо это делать в **OnClick()**, там и передаётся код, когда вы нажмёте на кнопку, а чтобы понять к какой кнопке это относится, вы можете в этом же методе выполнить **View.getId()**; и сравнить это ID с ID ваших кнопок, которые вы заранее сохранили, или выполнили бы **getId()** для ваших кнопок в **OnClick()**.